# OtpNode triggering IOException

Tags: java, erlang, erlang-otp

I experience a strange problem. Sometimes our Java app will not start and will raise an IOException when trying to open a `OtpNode`. Here is the code (really nothing special):

```
OtpNode oNode = new OtpNode(NODE);
oNode.setCookie(COOKIE);       
OtpMbox mbox = oNode.createMbox(MBOX);
```

`NODE`, `COOKIE` and `MBOX` are hardcoded constants. The error I get is:

```
class java.io.IOException,
'Nameserver not responding on Martin-PC when publishing jnode',
Stack trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@c3ea5a
```

That's it. And this happens only sometimes. I observed that when restarting the PC it happens.

Had anyone seen similar problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that after restrat the Erlang virtual machine sometimes is not running. So we need to start it first before Java OtpNode could be started:

`erl -sname whatever`

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html